# Is there any way to export breakpoint with IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, breakpoint

As the title describes, I'd like to export breakpoints in IDA Pro and load from another project. Is there such feature?

Comment: Try to use idc script, so you can export bp wherever you want.

Comment: What data about breakpoint do you want to export? Address, instruction... ?

Answer (score 4):

Open BreakPoint list with `{Cntrl-Alt-B}` then select all with `{Cntrl-A}`, then RightClick on selection, go to `Groups->Selection->ExportBreakPointAsIDC...`

to load them in another project go to `File->ScriptFile` and select saved idc file, then press `{Cntrl-Alt-B}` to see loaded BreakPionts.